# Let a SprideNode Blink

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I have a player and when the powerUp is running out, I want it to blink for a while.

This is what I tried to make it work:

```
 let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.3)
 let playerBlink = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.hide(), delay, SKAction.unhide()])
 self.player.run(playerBlink, withKey: "Blink")
```

I updated my code regarding the posts below, it is actually hiding and unhiding once. I want it to do that multiple times, If i use repeatActionForever it is not working and it is hidden all the time, if i use

```
self.actionRepeat = SKAction.repeat(playerBlink, count: 3)
```

and then run actionRepeat it is also just hidden once and not blinking

(If it does any difference, I run that code in the didBegin method)

Comment: Don’t use timer, attach this action to player directly, do not repeat  forever, repeat a count, and use `SKAction.hide` and `SKAction.unhide` After you make those changes, update the question because it will be easier for us to answer.

Comment: Also, if it is in the didbegin, then you could be attaching it multiple times

Comment: @Knight0fDragon its okay I handle it in a different way with if statements

Comment: @Knight0fDragon i updated my answer and now it is blinking once, how do I repeat the action now without using repeat for ever?

Comment: Problem is solved :  the sequence needs a delay after the unhide, then i can repeat it easily let playerBlink = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.hide(), delay, SKAction.unhide()])